# Deploy to heroku with a Makefile and Docker and Python

Tags: python, docker, heroku, makefile

For a school project, I'd like to deploy our app on Heroku. The app is made up of a frontend, made in reactjs, and compiled into static html then served by the backend which also handles the API and everything else.

The dockerfile works correctly, when in the repo, launch `make docker` and the image will be built and started. Go on `localhost:8080` and you should see a login prompt. If you get an error then you need a .env file containing the following

```
FLASK_DEBUG=True
FLASK_SECRET_KEY=ThisIsADevelopmentKey

FRONT_STATIC_FOLDER=../../frontend/build

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Then launch the image again using `docker run --env-file .env --name pymatcha --restart=always -p 8080:5000 -d pymatcha`

The problem is, when I push to my PR, Heroku creates a preview app but I get an error with Python. Either it's missing python3.7 entirely, or it's missing venv, or ensurepip. To counter that I tried to add an Aptfile with a Aptfile buildpack but it didn't work. Moving the Python buildpack up either.

Does anyone know a better solution to easily deploy to heroku my project ? either using our makefile during heroku's build process or by pushing a docker image to heroku in travis ?

Useful links about my question:
[Repository](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha)

[Current Heroku PR](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/pull/51)

[Frontend folder](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/tree/dev/frontend)

[Backend folder](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/tree/dev/backend)

[Dockerfile in Heroku PR](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/heroku/Dockerfile)

[app.json for Heroku in Heroku PR](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/heroku/app.json)

[Makefile in Heroku PR](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/heroku/Makefile)

Comment: Hi! Links are welcome but they also can be broken. Therefore you should include your files content direcly in your SO post.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think I'd remove the files eventually. I'll update the post/resolve it once I have found a solution (might go with aws)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely issue is that you’re using a build pack in the heroku stack instead of the docker “stack”. What that means is heroku will be trying to detect and build your app according to its rules, ignoring your dockerfile.

First update the stack:

```
heroku stack set docker -a <your app>
```

Then you should be able to locally build your docker container(s) and push them to the heroku [registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).

With heroku, like many deployment targets, you need to build the image either locally - or more preferably - in CI and push it  to the registry for deploy/release.

Comment: Would this work with preview apps too ? So that when I open a PR, if I have configured the CI correctly, it will make a preview app ?

Comment: Also it doesn't seem that I can set the stack for the whole pipeline 

Comment: I believe for the Review Apps you have to set it up via `app.json`. I believe combining that with [`heroku.yml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) May work.